# R adding names attribute to adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: r, matrix, graph

Let's say I have a matrix

```
mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

being an adjacency matrix of a graph. I need to add an attribute `names` with the names of the vertexes, so, in this case, `c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')`. If I was just to name these vertexes, I would simply go for

```
rownames(mat) <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
colnames(mat) <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
```

but this doesn't change the `names` attribute.
Writing

```
names(mat) <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
```

obviously changes "names" of the first 5 elements

```
 [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
[21] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

How shall I approach this?

Comment: `names` for `mattrix` is different. compared to `dimnames`.  as `matrix` is just a vector with `dim` attributes.  So, if you want to name the elements, it needs to supply names for the `length(mat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall what are matrices in R in the first place. Say, you have the following definition of a matrix:

```r
mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

This would be the same as if you wrote:

```
mat <- rep(1, each=25)
dim(mat) <- c(5, 5)
```

Now, if you'd like to name your rows and columns, there are numerous ways of achieving this:

```
dimnames(mat) <- list(
  c('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5'),
  c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5')
)

# or:

rownames(mat) <- c('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5')
colnames(mat) <- c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5')
```

Since both `names` and `dimnames` functions are primitives, it's hard to look up into the source code. However, I still did a bit of research, and you can see from [this example](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ec34d54d116feabd22ad6f8e1d2a50611d32eb75/src/include/Rdefines.h#L134-L140) that `dimnames` and `names` refer to completely different attributes of an object:

```c
#define GET_DIMNAMES(x)     Rf_getAttrib(x, R_DimNamesSymbol)
#define GET_NAMES(x)        Rf_getAttrib(x, R_NamesSymbol)
```

Everything above clearly indicates that `names()` and `dim<...>()` functions have completely different purposes and implementations on the core level.

To access your matrix by named dimensions, simply do:

```r
mat["r5", "c2"]
```

If you want to name every value of your vector / matrix, you might want to do something like this:

```r
names(mat) <- c('v1', 'v2', 'v3', ..., 'v25')

# or:

names(mat) <- paste0(rep('v', each=25), 1:25)

# access the vertex:

print(mat['v25'])
```

This will work, because, as I've shown you with my introduction example of the ways you can define matrices, `matrix` inherits `vector` class:

```r
Class "matrix" [package "methods"]

...

Extends: 
Class "array", directly
Class "structure", by class "array", distance 2
Class "vector", by class "array", distance 3, with explicit coerce
```

The functionality of `names` function didn't vanish, it's just the different ways of accessing matrices' values.